# Find string matching among columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
id      sentences                                           ind                 tar
0       In samples of depression injected intraneously...   depression        albumin
0       Monomethylmethacrylate in whole blood was asso...   depression        albumin
1       In samples of depression injected intraneously...   depression          hip
1       Monomethylmethacrylate in whole blood was asso...   depression          hip
2       The GVH kinetics and cellular characteristics ...   GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...  PFC
2       Effects on PFCgeneword responses to thymus-dep...   GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...  PFC
2       The unresponsive state which developed in GVHg...   GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...  PFC
2       Furthermore, GVHgeneword spleen cells suppress...   GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...  PFC
2       This active suppressor effect was found to be ...   GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...  PFC
2       The delayed transfer of GVHgeneword cells to i...   GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...  PFC
```

I want to keep only the rows that have either an `ind` or a `tar` value in the corresponding `sentence`.

The problem is that when I have more than one elements in either `ind` or `tar`, even if one of those elements exists on `sentence`, it doesn't match it, because it uses the whole string as a term. For example, at the 5th row, even though the word *GVH* exists in the sentence, it uses as `ind` the whole value `GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH` and not each GVH term separately. Can someone help how to fix this issue? Here's my code so far :

```
df['check_ind'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.ind in x.sentences, axis=1)
df['check_tar'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.tar in x.sentences, axis=1)
df = df.loc[(df['check_ind'] == True) | (df['check_tar'] == True)]

print(df.sentences.iloc[4], '\n')

print(df.indications.iloc[4], '\n')

print(df.targets.iloc[4], '\n')

print(df.check_ind.iloc[4], '\n')

print(df.check_tar.iloc[4], '\n')


>>>> The GVH kinetics and cellular characteristics indicated that suppressor T cells exert an anti-mitotic influence on antigen-stimulated B-cell proliferation. . 

>>>> GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH 

>>>> PFC 

>>>> False (This should return TRUE since GVH is in the sentence)

>>>> False
```

Data:

```
{'id': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 'sentences': ['In samples of depression injected intraneously...',
  'Monomethylmethacrylate in whole blood was asso...',
  'In samples of depression injected intraneously...',
  'Monomethylmethacrylate in whole blood was asso...',
  'The GVH kinetics and cellular characteristics ...',
  'Effects on PFCgeneword responses to thymus-dep...',
  'The unresponsive state which developed in GVHg...',
  'Furthermore, GVHgeneword spleen cells suppress...',
  'This active suppressor effect was found to be ...',
  'The delayed transfer of GVHgeneword cells to i...'],
 'ind': ['depression', 'depression', 'depression',
         'depression', 'GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...',
         'GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...', 'GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...',
         'GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...', 'GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...',
         'GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...'],
 'tar': ['albumin', 'albumin', 'hip', 'hip', 'PFC', 'PFC',
         'PFC', 'PFC', 'PFC', 'PFC']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently treating `x.ind` as if it were a simple value.

Conceptually `x.ind` is not a single value, but rather a comma-separated list of values.

In python, you can transform a comma-separated list into an actual python list using `x.split(',')`. In addition, `str.strip()` is useful to remove possible spaces (for instance, if you have `"GVH ,GVH "`, the spaces should probably be ignored).

Finally, builtin function `any` and `all` are convenient to broadcast a condition to a list.

```py
df['check_ind'] = df.apply(lambda x: any(v.strip() in x.sentences for v in x.split(',')), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first `concat` "ind" and "tar" columns so that you could do only one evaluation.

Then use `str.split` + `explode` + `apply` an evaluator to check if any "ind" or "tar" exist. Then `groupby` + `any` to get back into original shape:

```
new_df = pd.concat((df[['id','sentences','ind']], df[['id','sentences','tar']].rename(columns={'tar':'ind'})))
new_df['ind'] = new_df['ind'].str.split(',')
msk = new_df.explode('ind').apply(lambda x: x['ind'] in x['sentences'], axis=1).groupby(level=0).any()
out = df[msk]
```

Output:

```
   id                                          sentences                 ind      tar  
0   0  In samples of depression injected intraneously...          depression  albumin  
2   1  In samples of depression injected intraneously...          depression      hip  
4   2  The GVH kinetics and cellular characteristics ...  GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...      PFC  
5   2  Effects on PFCgeneword responses to thymus-dep...  GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...      PFC  
6   2  The unresponsive state which developed in GVHg...  GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...      PFC  
7   2  Furthermore, GVHgeneword spleen cells suppress...  GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...      PFC  
9   2  The delayed transfer of GVHgeneword cells to i...  GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH...      PFC
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the terms in ind that are comma separated always duplicates?

If they are you can try the following:

```
df['check_ind'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.ind.split(',')[0] in x.sentences, axis=1)
```

This searches for the first term before the comma.

Comment: They aren't always duplicate

Answer (score 0):

An efficient method would be to use a regex per group (as you have many duplicates of ind/tar combinations:

```
import re
regex = df[['ind', 'tar']].apply(lambda s: '|'.join(map(re.escape, set(x for e in s.values
                                                                       for x in e.split(',')))),
                                                    axis=1)

df['match'] = df.groupby(regex).apply(lambda s: s['sentences'].str.contains(s.name)).droplevel(0)
```

output:

```
   id                                          sentences              ind      tar  match
0   0  In samples of depression injected intraneously...       depression  albumin   True
1   0  Monomethylmethacrylate in whole blood was asso...       depression  albumin  False
2   1  In samples of depression injected intraneously...       depression      hip   True
3   1  Monomethylmethacrylate in whole blood was asso...       depression      hip  False
4   2  The GVH kinetics and cellular characteristics ...  GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH      PFC   True
5   2  Effects on PFCgeneword responses to thymus-dep...  GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH      PFC   True
6   2  The unresponsive state which developed in GVHg...  GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH      PFC   True
7   2  Furthermore, GVHgeneword spleen cells suppress...  GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH      PFC   True
8   2  This active suppressor effect was found to be ...  GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH      PFC  False
9   2  The delayed transfer of GVHgeneword cells to i...  GVH,GVH,GVH,GVH      PFC   True
```

regex/group:

```
0    albumin|depression
1    albumin|depression
2        hip|depression
3        hip|depression
4               GVH|PFC
5               GVH|PFC
6               GVH|PFC
7               GVH|PFC
8               GVH|PFC
9               GVH|PFC
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define a method which checks both and then use it in `apply()`. This method can also be used to split the values in each of these rows, assuming `,` is never used in text and all lists are in this exact notation without spaces.

```
import pandas

def sent_contains_ind_or_tar(row):
    return any(ind in row["sentences"] for ind in row["ind"].split(",")) or any(ind in row["sentences"] for ind in row["tar"].split(","))

df = df[df.apply(sent_contains_ind_or_tar, axis=1)]
```

For example:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[1, "abc", "u", "v"],
                       [2, "xyz", "x", "z"],
                       [3, "xya", "x", "z"]],
                      columns=["id", "sentences", "ind", "tar"])
print(df)
>    id sentences ind tar
  0   1       abc   u   v
  1   2       xyz   x   z
  2   3       xya   x   z


def sent_contains_ind_or_tar(row):
    return any(ind in row["sentences"] for ind in row["ind"].split(",")) or any(ind in row["sentences"] for ind in row["tar"].split(","))

df = df[df.apply(sent_contains_ind_or_tar, axis=1)]
print(df)
>    id sentences ind tar
  1   2       xyz   x   z
```

**Edit: Added list case to method**

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I have already used the code line that checks whether ind **or** tar is in the sentence. The problem is when I have more than one terms in either ind or tar, and how to split the terms and check the sentence.